# Batch object allocation java

Tags: java, constructor, memory-management

Is there a way to batch allocate a bunch of objects?

I have the following slow piece of code and want to make it fast:

```
final int N = 10000000;
Node[] a = new Node[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  a[i] = new Node(-1, null);
}
```

I'm hoping that there's some low-level method (like those available for Arrays) that can do the job quickly.

Comment: How fast is it, how fast do you need it? Isn't it fast?

Comment: What suggests to you that this piece of code is the bottleneck?  Can you provide any profiler data?

Answer (score 2):

No! There is no built-in feature in language. An `object` is allocated when you allocate using `new` construct.

Answer (score 1):

How large is `Node`? Is it a long living object? The reason this code is slow is because you're probably hitting the GC. Run this code with a profiler and see how much time your program spends in GC. What you can do is increase the heap size, and probably set survivor space to 0, so that your objects go directly to tenured space from the young generation without being copied between survivor spaces. If this kind of allocation happens often, increase young generation ratio so that the whole thing fits in there at once.

more information about gc tuning: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html

**EDIT** To give you an estimate of how much memory you need to have - the array itself is about 40 megabytes, and then whatever the size of all nodes is, starting with minimum of 80 MB (each object has 8 bytes overhead + size of its fields). If you have a 64-bit JVM, you can easily double these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Does anything interesting occur in Node's ctor?

Java has low overhead for allocating memory.  You pay for most of it when the GC runs.

Comment: Nothing interesting happens: the arguments are assigned to fields.

Comment: As @AVD states, there's nothing built into Java to help.  There's no concept of stack allocation for objects (as in C++).  Maybe you can try sharing Node objects if they're stateless?